# The type or namespace name 'OpenIdConnectOptions' could not be found while upgrading my ASP.NET Core 2.2 to 3.1

Tags: asp.net-core-3.1, asp.net-core-2.2

I am trying to upgrade my ASP.NET Core 2.2 to 3.1 but getting below error.
Not Sure how to resolve it.

I am getting below error

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error CS0234  The type or namespace name 'OpenIdConnect' does not exist
> in the namespace 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication' (are you
> missing an assembly reference?)
>
> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error CS0246  The type or namespace name 'OpenIdConnectOptions' could
> not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
> reference?)
>
> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error CS1061  'AuthenticationBuilder' does not contain a definition for
> 'AddOpenIdConnect' and no accessible extension method
> 'AddOpenIdConnect' accepting a first argument of type
> 'AuthenticationBuilder' could be found (are you missing a using
> directive or an assembly reference?)

> Error CS0006  Metadata file 'C:....\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\aa.dll' could not be found

I have this using directive in my solution.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect
```

Comment: Did you try to update the latest nuget package of ASP.NET Core ?

Answer (score 0):

run the following in your Package manager console

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect -Version 6.0.4
```

For .Net 6